# Return one field after creation via post-request in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

This is my class-based view:

```
class PurchaseAPICreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
```

and serializer:

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = "__all__"
```

Get-request return me all fields, but I need only `id`. I tried `fields = ('id',)`. But post request needs all fields for serialization. I did this, but think it shouldn't work in this way.

```
class PurchaseAPICreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = PurchaseSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({
            'id': serializer.data[len(serializer.data)-1]['id']
        })
```

How I can get only id in right way?

Answer (score 1):

You can set write or read only in extra_kwargs in the Meta class of a serializer.
E.g.

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
             'field_1': {'write_only': True},
             'field...N': {'write_only': True},
             'id': {'read_only': True}
        }
```